# How to create a layer to invert a softmax (TensforFlow,python)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, softmax, deconvolution

I am building a deconvolution network. I would like to add a layer to it which is the reverse of a softmax. I tried to write a basic python function that returns the inverse of a softmax for a given matrix and put that in a tensorflow Lambda and add it to my model.
I have no error but when I doing a predict I only have 0 at the exit. When I don't add this layer to my network I have output something other than zeros. This therefore justifies that they are due to my inv_softmax function which is bad.
Can you enlighten me how to proceed?

I define my funct as this :

```
def inv_softmax(x):
   C=0
   S = np.zeros((1,1,10)) #(1,1,10) is the shape of the datas that my layer will receive
   try:
      for j in range(np.max(np.shape(x))):
         C+=np.exp(x[0,0,j])
      for i in range(np.max(np.shape(x))):
         S[0,0,i] = np.log(x[0,0,i]+C
   except ValueError:
      print("ValueError in inv_softmax")
      pass
   S = tf.convert_to_tensor(S,dtype=tf.float32)
   return S
```

I add it to my network as :

```
x = ...
x = layers.Lambda(lambda x : inv_softmax(x),name='inv_softmax',output_shape=[1,1,10])(x)
x = ...
```

If you need more of my code or others informations ask me please.

Comment: Another information (maybe useful), when I have an array of shape (1,1,10) for example with values ​​into it and I do tf.convert_to_tensor (My_array, dtype = tf.float32) and print this thing I only get "tf.Tensor 'Const' shape (1,1,10) dtype = float32" and no values. When I check on the internet people get the values ​​when they print it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def inv_softmax(x, C):
   return tf.math.log(x) + C

import math
input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,10))
x = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x : inv_softmax(x, math.log(10.)),name='inv_softmax')(input)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input, outputs=x)

a = tf.zeros([1, 1, 10])
a = tf.nn.softmax(a)
a = model(a)
print(a.numpy())
```

Comment: I can invert softmax if I store the xi when they go into softmax in my convolution network.(that's not what I did thanks for the remark I'll change it)
My xi are always different from 0 and 1.
But the problem stay the same to implement my funct into my model, I do something wrong I think.
Si=exp(xi)/SUM(exp(xi)) <=> xi = ln(Si) + ln(SUM(exp(xi))
ln(SUM(exp(xi)) is a constat that I compute when I'm making softmax in my conv model.

Comment: My tensorflow has no attribute math :(

Comment: What is tf version ?

Comment: v0.12.0rcl I can't change it

Comment: try np.log(). In my tf (ver. 2.3.1) it is impossible

Comment: I can put K.log from keras.backend ? it work to compile the model with K.log, np.log didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Thanks it works !
I put :

```
import keras.backend as K

def inv_softmax(x,C):
   return K.log(x)+K.log(C)
```