How to get the output of the model, before the softmax, without chaning the model architecture?
I have a trained sequential keras model.
The last layer is a Dense layer with softmax activation function:
model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(...)
model.add(...)
model.add(...)
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(50, activation='softmax'))

How can I get the the output of the model, before the softmax, without changing the model architecture ? I have trained model, which I can't change or train.
I have tried with:
probs = model.predict(X_train)
logits = probs - np.log(np.sum(np.exp(probs), axis=-1, keepdims=True))

But it seems that if I'm running softmax on logtis, it give me different results from probs.
def softmax(x):
    e_x = np.exp(x - np.max(x))  
    return e_x / e_x.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)

probabilities = softmax(logits)


There is actually no need to invert the logits.
You can just create the same model architecture in a new keras.models.Model instance, without the softmax activation in the last layer, load the weights of the original model into the new model (using model.load_weights), and then you would have a model without a softmax at the end, where you can make predictions.
model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(...)
model.add(...)
model.add(...)
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(50, activation='linear'))

model.load_weights('model.h5')

# Now predicts logits.
model.predict(some_input)


This sounds overcomplicated. Also, please add code to demonstrate the workflow.

@Innat It is actually shorter than your answer, so not overcomplicated at all.

Actually my answer is shorter than yours if you only count the inv_softmax method. Additionally I added full working code and proof. Your answer is fine but overcomplicated in a sense that I had to rewirte model definition and also might be an issue to adopt for saved-model format. :)

@Innat Any answer is better if you cherrypick parts, conceptually my answer actually answers the question, inverting the softmax does not give you the same original logits always, there is some loss of information.

Agreed that some information would be loss. And so, if exact matching is highly desired, then this is the way. But the OP already tried reverse method and I assumed he/she was well aware of that. Anyway, thanks.

You can reverse the softmax back to logits in the following ways.
# options 1
# ref. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64668809/9215780
def inv_softmax(x, C):
    logits = np.log(x) + C
    return logits

# options 2
def inv_softmax(x):
    logits = np.log(x / (1 - x))
    return logits 

Here is some dummy code to test them.
num_class=50
inputs = Input(shape=(5,))
x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(inputs)
x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(32, activation='relu')(x)
outputs = Dense(num_class, activation='softmax')(x)
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

a = tf.ones(shape=(2, 5))
y_pred_prob = model(a)
y_pred_prob.shape # TensorShape([2, 50])

# following option 1
logits = inv_softmax(y_pred_prob, num_class)
logits.shape # (2, 50)

y_pred_prob_reproduce = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
y_pred_prob_reproduce.shape # TensorShape([2, 50])

y_pred_prob[0]
<tf.Tensor: shape=(50,), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([0.02209216, 0.01324271, 0.01495313, 0.0182846 , 0.02364523,
       0.01963637, 0.02066819, 0.02271825, 0.02229412, 0.01854686,
       0.01951347, 0.02007069, 0.02835885, 0.01483266, 0.02553979,
       0.01616779, 0.01538332, 0.01937215, 0.01792852, 0.01752241,
       0.02167817, 0.01575256, 0.0232809 , 0.0204947 , 0.01880379,
       0.01848676, 0.0199989 , 0.02911243, 0.02096296, 0.02170451,
       0.02149592, 0.02127673, 0.01858926, 0.02001583, 0.01901014,
       0.01976348, 0.01502533, 0.01940756, 0.01502022, 0.02546986,
       0.02210576, 0.01966349, 0.01942356, 0.02224619, 0.02430816,
       0.0187437 , 0.01451708, 0.02327427, 0.01841178, 0.02118474],
      dtype=float32)>

y_pred_prob_reproduce[0]
<tf.Tensor: shape=(50,), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([0.02209212, 0.01324273, 0.01495312, 0.01828457, 0.02364521,
       0.0196364 , 0.02066822, 0.02271822, 0.02229412, 0.01854688,
       0.01951349, 0.02007072, 0.02835883, 0.01483268, 0.02553976,
       0.01616781, 0.0153833 , 0.01937212, 0.01792852, 0.01752243,
       0.02167813, 0.01575255, 0.02328094, 0.02049471, 0.01880377,
       0.01848677, 0.01999888, 0.02911241, 0.02096297, 0.02170452,
       0.02149589, 0.02127676, 0.01858924, 0.02001582, 0.01901012,
       0.01976348, 0.01502534, 0.01940755, 0.01502024, 0.02546991,
       0.02210577, 0.01966346, 0.01942355, 0.0222462 , 0.02430819,
       0.01874369, 0.01451708, 0.02327428, 0.01841175, 0.02118476],
      dtype=float32)>


tolerance = 1e-6
is_equal = np.allclose(
    y_pred_prob, y_pred_prob_reproduce, atol=tolerance
) # OK

